# jsPDF throws an error "Type of text must be string or array"

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sharepoint-2013, jspdf

All,

I try to generate a jsPDF using the data in Sharepoint 2013.

```
var objSender= "";
var fileName= "";
function printTable(sender) {
// To generate pdf document using list item data

objSender = sender;
var promise = $.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Request For Information')/items('" + getParameterByName('ID') + "')",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }
});
promise.done(successFunction);
promise.fail(errorFunction);
}
function successFunction(data) {
l = {
    orientation: 'p',
    unit: 'px',
    format: 'a4',
    compress: true,
    fontSize: 28,
    lineHeight: 0,
    autoSize: true,
    printHeaders: true
};
```

I get an error saying the result in d.data.object is undefined or null.
I read that this can be caused because javascript is asynchronous which means the jsPDF lines are executed before the data is loaded.

Any help is appreciated,

Marco